# nginx deny access to files in folder but not for php download

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-config

is it possible to deny access to files in a folder with nginx, but that for example the following code still starts a direct download (and doesn't deny it):

```
$file_url = 'http://www.myremoteserver.com/file.exe';
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file_url) . "\""); 
readfile($file_url);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are probably looking for the `X-Accel-Redirect` nginx feature; check [this](https://kovyrin.net/2006/11/01/nginx-x-accel-redirect-php-rails/) example.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Wow, I never seen this in nginx, seems it's quite shinny, is there any impelemntation for apache, or we need to manually check it one by one?

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto An apache equivalent may be mod_xsendfile ([homepage](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/), [GitHub](https://github.com/nmaier/mod_xsendfile)).